# c# zip files using Microsoft.Deployment.Compression.Zip

Tags: c#

I need to use the following:

```
    using Microsoft.Deployment.Compression.Zip;
```

From looking online it says I need the following reference dlls

```
    Microsoft.Deployment.Compression.dll
    Microsoft.Deployment.Compression.Zip.dll
```

but I could not find these in the .NET folder.

Just as a FYI, below is how I plan to use it.

```
    // CREATING ZIP FILE BY ADDING LIST OF FILES
    ZipInfo zip = new ZipInfo(@"C:\testarchive1.zip");
    List<strng> files = new List<string>();
    files.Add(@"C:\test1.txt");
    files.Add(@"C:\test2.txt");
    files.Add(@"C:\test3.txt");
    zip.PackFiles(null, files, null);

    // CREATING ZIP FILE BY ADDING FOLDER (WITH SUB-FOLDERS) USING MAXIMUM COMPRESSION

     zip = new ZipInfo(@"C:\testarchive2.zip"); 

     zip.Pack(@"C:\Test", true, Microsoft.Deployment.Compression.CompressionLevel.Max, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Sample code :

```
 using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
 {
     // add this map file into the "images" directory in the zip archive
     zip.AddFile("c:\\images\\personal\\7440-N49th.png", "images");
     // add the report into a different directory in the archive
     zip.AddFile("c:\\Reports\\2008-Regional-Sales-Report.pdf", "files");
     zip.AddFile("ReadMe.txt");
     zip.Save("MyZipFile.zip");
 }
```

Just as easy as your example.

Comment: Hi MuhammadA, what .NET vesion is this supporte on?

Answer (score 5):

That library is not part of the .NET Framework, but part of [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/) (Windowx Installer XML).

If you're using .NET 4.5 you could use the [`ZipFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx) class instead, or choose a third-party library like [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/)

Comment: D Stanley you are totally correct.. I totally forgot about that.. +1

Comment: Hi Stan, I am using .NET 4. Any idea what the best way I can do the zip in c#?

Comment: There are [several third-party libraries](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+zip+library).  I can't say which one is "best" without knowing your detailed needs.  Research them and choose one for yourself.  My guess is any of them suit your basic needs effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from MSDN website example

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
            string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";
            string extractPath = @"c:\example\extract";

            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);

            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my using looks like using Microsoft.Deployment.Compression.Zip; but where do I find the .dlls? I do not see it in the .NET folder when I do add reference

Comment: Also can you tell  me what the name of the dlls I need and where I can find them. I do not see them in the .NET folder

Comment: Web Dev I was not aware that you didn't have these .Dll's you could do the following with my next edit.. give me a sec D Stanley has already provided the links